# Generating static docs

Tags: scala, swagger

I am trying to run static-docs.sh from the swagger-codegen project, but I keep getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot figure out how to run target: ./bin/Version.scala` ...

it ends with `Please set scalaVersion := "" in build.sbt and run ./sbt assembly`.

I am running on Ubuntu 12.0.4, java version "1.6.0_33", Scala code runner version 2.9.1 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL

I have set the scalaVersion in 
swagger-codegen-master/build.sbt file (`scalaVersion := "2.9.1"`), but I still keep getting the same Error.

Could anyone give me a straightforward guide how to run that .sh file please?

Comment: There's a list of prerequisites in the codegen's website. I'd start by making sure you they are installed and the defaults - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

You need swagger 2.10.4 to build with ./sbt assembly then it should work by default.